# how can i access an array in my controller file to view file in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

controller file

```
public function get_product(){
    //$idval = $this->input->get();
        $productID =  $this->uri->segment(3);
        $datas   = array();
        $this->load->model('product_modal');
        $datas = $this->product_modal->get_productdetail($productID);
        print_r($datas);
        echo $datas[0]->name;
        $this->load->view('product_detail', $datas);
}
```

view file

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach($result as $key => $array){?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label >Product name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="p_name" name="p_name" value="<?php echo $array[0]->name; ?>" > <br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label >Product Desc</label></td>
    <td><textarea type="text"  class="form-control" id="p_desc" name="p_desc" value="<?php echo $array[0]->description;?>" > </textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label >Qty</label></td>
    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="p_qty" name="p_qty" value="<?php echo $array[0]->qty;?>" > <br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label >Rate</label></td>
    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="p_rate" name="p_rate" value="<?php echo $array[0]->rate;?>" > <br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label >Amount</label></td>
    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="p_amt" name="p_amt" value="<?php echo $array[0]->amt;?>" > <br /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }?>
```

my output array like this

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [name] => trans [description] => fgt [qty] => 560 [rate] => 12 [amt] => 6720 ) )
```

how can i access an array in my controller file  to view file

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: result
>
> Filename: views/product_detail.php
>
> Line Number: 26
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Product-Store\application\views\product_detail.php
>   Line: 26 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Product-Store\application\controllers\Product.php
>   Line: 69 Function: view
>
> File: F:\xampp\htdocs\Product-Store\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/product_detail.php
>
> Line Number: 26
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Product-Store\application\views\product_detail.php
>   Line: 26 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Product-Store\application\controllers\Product.php
>   Line: 69 Function: view
>
> File: F:\xampp\htdocs\Product-Store\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: `print_r($datas)` it will give you the result you want.

Comment: it print as an array but i need to fill each array value in each text boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this `Message: Undefined variable: result` message because there is no index with `result` key.

Try
controller:

```
 $this->load->view('product_detail', array("data"=> $datas));
```

in view

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach($data as $key => $array){?>
```

Comment: @KalaiM : Glad to know that.